# How to remove specific indices from a filtered list that has duplicate entries?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a `TableView` backed by a `SortedList` wrapping a `FilteredList` wrapping an `ObservableList`. The items in the filtered list can be duplicated. That is to say, it can be the case that `list.get(5) == list.get(10)`.

The user can select rows on the `TableView` and press delete. When they do, the items that are selected are supposed to be removed, and no others.

I have tried two solutions, both of which present problems:

**Using list.remove ( Object ) on the underlying ObservableList** - Because the list can have duplicated items, all copies of the object are removed rather than just the selected one(s).

```
public void removeItemsAtIndices ( List <Integer> indices ) {

    List <Item> removeMe = new ArrayList<Item> ();

    for ( int index : indices ) {
        removeMe.add( currentListSorted.get( index ) );
    }

    items.removeAll( removeMe );
}
```

**using list.remove ( index ) on the SortedList** - The filtered list throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

```
public void removeItemsAtIndices ( List <Integer> indices ) {
    Collections.sort( indices, Collections.reverseOrder() );

    for( int index : indices ) {
        currentListSorted.remove( index ); //Exception here
    }
}
```

Here is how I'm setting up my Lists:

```
private final ObservableList <Item> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); 
private final FilteredList <Item> currentListFiltered = new FilteredList <Item>( items, p -> true );
private final SortedList <Item> currentListSorted = new SortedList <CurrentListTrack>( currentListFiltered );
```

Is there some way to remove items:

1. From a sorted list
2. Targeting by index of the filtered & sorted list
3. Without removing non-targeted duplicates?

The only solution I can come up with at the moment is to make it so each item is unique (i.e it's impossible that `list.get(5) == list.get(10)`). I am hoping to avoid this by finding another solution.

---

P.S. If for some reason it is useful, here is the code that determines the selected indices:

```
removeMenuItem.setOnAction( new EventHandler <ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle ( ActionEvent event ) {
        ObservableList <Integer> selectedIndexes = currentListTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices();
        List <Integer> removeMe = new ArrayList<> ( selectedIndexes );
        removeItemsAtIndices ( removeMe );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TransformationList` (of which both `SortedList` and `FilteredList` are implementations) has a [`getSourceIndex(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/collections/transformation/TransformationList.html#getSourceIndex-int-) method that "translates" the index in the transformed list to the index in its source (underlying) list. So `currentListSorted(index)` gives the index in the filtered list of an item that has the provided index in the sorted list, and `currentListFiltered(index)` gives the index in the original `items` list of an item that has the provided index in the filtered list.

So you can do

```
items.remove(currentListFiltered.getSourceIndex(
    currentListSorted.getSourceIndex(index)
));
```

to remove the item at a specific index in the "index coordinates" of the visible table items (the sorted list).

Of course, you need to be careful with the loops in your code here, because the indexing will change when items are removed. (This would be true too if you were simply removing items by index from a simple list.)

So you probably need something along the following lines:

```
List<Integer> indicesToBeRemoved = new ArrayList<>();
for (int index : indices) { // indices in the sorted list
    indicesToBeRemoved.add(currentListFiltered.getSourceIndex(
        currentListSorted.getSourceIndex(index)));
}
// sort with largest index first, as removing an item with
// a given index will not change the indices of items with small indices:
indicesToBeRemoved.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder()); 
for (Integer index : indicesToBeRemoved) {
    // be careful to explicitly unbox the Integer here, 
    // to avoid collision between remove(Object) and remove(int):
    items.remove(index.intValue());
}
```