# Why does a Sort on an ObservableList not allow me to select and remove a TableView Item?

Tags: javafx, observable, tableview

I have a TableView that has a list of position numbers.  When i select an individual position number then click the remove button, the code below removes that item from the database (still works) but removing the position number from the tableview now gives me an error.

```
public void removePositionNumber() {
        //load the class that will handle the connections to the database
        PositionNumberConnectionShell pncs = new PositionNumberConnectionShell();
        //creat some fx lists
        ObservableList<PositionNumbersDbm> selectedRows, allPositionNumbers;
        //get all of the items in the TableView
        allPositionNumbers = positionNumbersDbmTableView.getItems();
        //this gives us the rows that were selected
        selectedRows = positionNumbersDbmTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();

        //loop over the selected rows and remove the PositionNumbersDbm objects from the table
        for (PositionNumbersDbm positionNumber : selectedRows)
        {
            pncs.deleteSingle(positionNumber);
            allPositionNumbers.remove(positionNumber);
        }
    }
```

This started happening when i began sorting the ObservableList prior to adding to the table view, as follows;

This works fine for adding items to the TableView;

```
positionNumbersDbmTableView.setItems(olpn);
```

Although the sorting works correctly i cannot remove items i have selected;

`positionNumbersDbmTableView.setItems(olpn.sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(PositionNumbersDbm::getPositionNumber))  )`;

I once thought the property that might be giving me the problem so i added a int positionNumber_test with getter and setter access but i still had the same issue trying to add or remove from the list. I first load the TableView, when the scene is loaded and the add and remove are done well after this initialization period.

Here is the data class i use for position numbers;

```
public class PositionNumbersDbm {
    private SimpleIntegerProperty positionNumber;
    public PositionNumbersDbm(int positionNumber) {
        this.positionNumber = new SimpleIntegerProperty(positionNumber);
    }

    public int getPositionNumber() {        return positionNumber.get();    }
    public SimpleIntegerProperty positionNumberProperty() {        return positionNumber;    }
    public void setPositionNumber(int positionNumber) {        this.positionNumber.set(positionNumber);    }
}
```

Here is the error that i get when i try to remove the individually selected item from the ObservableList taken from the Tableview;

Top of the error message  .....

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
```

Bottom of the error message...

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:161)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(AbstractList.java:374)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.remove(AbstractCollection.java:293)
    at reportmefx.generalsetup.baselinedetail.positionnumber.Controller_PositionNumbers.removePositionNumberButtonPressed(Controller_PositionNumbers.java:95)
    ... 62 more
```

Line 95 represents the following;

```
allPositionNumbers.remove(positionNumber);
```

I am confused, perhaps of when the sortation is done or if the original index is maintained after the sort?  This part f the error confuses me;

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

I suspect this has to do with a miss pointed selection?  Help understanding this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: SortedList is unmodifiable (as the error tells you) - walk up the source chain and modify the top observableList

Comment: Thank you, i will dig deeper.

Comment: Just to note: `ObservableList#sorted(Comparator)` does not behave the same as `List#sort(Comparator)`. The latter sorts the list in-place. But the former returns a `SortedList` (an implementation of `ObservableList`) which is a sorted **view** over the source list. Since it's only a view it is unmodifiable. You have to modify the source list directly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove specific indices from a filtered list that has duplicate entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48490831/how-to-remove-specific-indices-from-a-filtered-list-that-has-duplicate-entries)

Comment: Yes these are great answers and were very helpful.  The meaning of my "I will dig deeper" referred to my missing the unmodifiable aspect of the sorted list. Thanks again!